# asp.net website (development) takes very long to load first time (C# / Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-express, cassini

I know this has been asked quite some time regarding production websites.  However, I would like to know if there is anything that could possibly be done to speed up the initial load time of a website, during development.  I've been timing it and it takes up to 50seconds to load the initial homepage. Subsequent loads take only 1 - 3seconds.  Also, when I 'break' the execution, it does not stop at any location in the code but just says 'No source code found'.

The output window lists a lot of:

```
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0a486d18\8cf9a7c5\App_Web_scrollablecontent.ascx.fdc5856b.1gwjfghw.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0a486d18\8cf9a7c5\App_Web_newarticles.ascx.44e66049.4ezrpblb.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0a486d18\8cf9a7c5\App_Web_rightcolumnmediumrectangleadvert.ascx.57649735.kymbya94.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0a486d18\8cf9a7c5\App_Web_main.master.cdcab7d2.lei5axii.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0a486d18\8cf9a7c5\App_Web_articleheadline.ascx.c8a8415c.klhhkoqx.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0a486d18\8cf9a7c5\App_Web_articleheadlines.ascx.c8a8415c.ikuqn1xd.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0a486d18\8cf9a7c5\App_Web_panel.ascx.fdc5856b.a0mhhnzv.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0a486d18\8cf9a7c5\App_Web_articlelistingitempanel.ascx.2acfc5c3.nqj5yies.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0a486d18\8cf9a7c5\App_Web_otherheadlinespanel.ascx.205896d5.cg_7tycu.dll', Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\0a486d18\8cf9a7c5\App_Web_articleheadlinesandotherheadlines.ascx.1d347881.zttdxgh7.dll', Symbols loaded.
```

Also, the output window writes each line quite slowly, at a rate of 2 - 3 lines per second (i.e for each component).  The website uses loads of user controls to keep it more organised.

Is there anything that can be done to speed up the initial page load for development?  It really wastes a lot of developer's time, having to wait all this time for the initial page load.  I've been experimenting both with Cassini and IIS Express, but both seem to have similar loading times.

Comment: I've worked with some very big projects (with allot of initialization code) in VS and never seen it take that long. What are the specifications of the system you are using? Also its really hard for us to tell you anything unless we understand more about what your application does on startup that might be causing these delays. For example, do you execute anything in the Global.asax file?

Comment: Have you tried "Edit and continue"? Can save a lot of time on large projects

Answer (score 2):

Are you generating all your assemblies all times? I used to do it but now I set the build option (in solution properties) only in my working project. All of other dll will not be generated anymore unless I do manually.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by 'generating all your assemblies all times?'

Comment: Sorry for the delay. If your solution has several projects, you are gonig to generate each assembly each time if you rebuild or clean your solution. Your other projects will be compiled each time you do rebuild or clean (and buid).

Answer (score 0):

Because it is compiling your application for the first time since the last publish. that is why it is slow for the first time. it re-compiles once after every publish. So, when ever you run/debug/compile it takes time recompile depending on the size of your application/libraries.

you could unload libraries and assemblies you are using in your website to make it load faster.

Comment: How do you unload libraries / assemblies which are being used?